# Can we interact with a function in the blockchain but isn't mentioned in the ABI?

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan, web3.py, abi

There's a public contract (with no access control) and it has a function which is also public and has no access control and can be called by anyone, as example :

```
contract example {
   function example_func(address addr) public returns(uint256) {
     // some stuff
  }
}
```

However this function isn't mentioned in the ABI nor exists on the "write" section,

Is it possible to interact with that function by an external node and self generated ABI code ?

Comment: Even if you were purposely given an incomplete ABI you cal call that function if it is public. I'm just curious regarding your sentence "nor exists on the "write" section" , are you talking about the etherscan contract page ? If so, please give the link of the contract's page.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I wanted, the "write section" from etherscan is just a user interface that runs with it's abi (etherscan's abi) means if funciton isn't existed on abi won't be shown in the write section at etherscan (https://etherscan.io/address/0xaddress#writeContract)
What I wanted is can we call a function that isn't mentioned in the ABI, and thankfully you've responded with the answer
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey @Sky,
1. Supposing you go to some contract (sorry for not providing it) like etherscan.io/address/0xaddress#code
2. Then you'll see a contract there which is public with no access control (like ownable ...etc), and inside it there's a function which is also public with access controls either (like onlyOwner modifier) which makes it can be called publicly
3. However in the abi that function isn't mentioned, nor in Address>Code>writeContract section
is in that case can we connect to it even if it's not mentioned in the abi ?
Thanks to Hroussile who've already answered !